# linear gradient not working with image in IE 11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I use this and this work in Chrome

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,70%) 70%,rgba(255,255,255,70%) 70%),url(Image-url) no-repeat!important;
```

but this not working in IE 11... how i can fix this ?  please help

Comment: remove `-webkit-` and `rgba(255,255,255,70%)` should be `rgba(255,255,255,0.7)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif, can you post your solution as an answer to this question? Your solution is working, op can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I voted to close the question as *typo* because If we google linear-gradient we can easily get the correct syntax that we need to use in all the browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following, the linear gradient should work cross-browser:

```
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 70%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff",endColorstr="#ffffff",GradientType=1);
```

Also, you should add the image.